# Change Time format

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, momentjs

I have a time string and I want to convert it to have `:` between the hour and minutes. Any suggestions on how to take the sting and change it. I’m assuming I need to use regular expression but not sure how to format that code. Any suggestions would be great.

```js
var number = '1340';
moment(number).format('hh:mm')
console.log(number)
// The output I want would be 13:40
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Stick a `:` before the last 2 digits.  This makes the assumption that your minutes are padded with zeroes if not 2 digits long:

```js
console.log('1340'.replace(/\d{2}$/, m => ':' + m));
```

Comment: you can use this also


`const time = "1340";
console.log([time.slice(0, 2), ":", time.slice(2)].join(""));`

Comment: @kennethreyt but only if always 4 long

Answer (score 1):

First off, in the code you show you are outputing the original string not the result from moment.js.

If you want to use moment, you'll need to tell it what format your string is:

```
var number = '1340';
var time = moment(number, 'hhmm').format('hh:mm')
console.log(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var number = '1340';
    console.log(number.slice(0, 2)+":"+number.slice(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment needs a date.

You want something like this

```js
const pad = num => ("00"+num).slice(-2);
const hhmm = str => {
  const mm = str.slice(-2)
  const hh = str.slice(0,-2)
  return `${pad(hh)}:${pad(mm)}`;
};

console.log(hhmm('1340'))
console.log(hhmm('340'))
console.log(hhmm('40'))
console.log(hhmm('0'))
console.log(hhmm(''))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const number = "1340";
const time = `${number.substring(0,2)}:${number.substring(2,4)}`;
console.log(time);
```

Comment: That is assuming a string of always 4 long